# How to fix "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: bootstrap.pypa.io"

Tags: python, pip

I am getting

> could not resolve host :bootstrap.pypa.io

error when trying to install virtualenv

I am trying to come up with a Django project, I have python 3 in my Mac and I need to use `virtualenv` for creating a virtual environment, I used `pip install virtualenv` to install virtual env but I got an error

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for virtualenv

I found a solution for this in Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265809/7300334) which was to update pip using

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python`

but I am getting

> could not resolve host :bootstrap.pypa.io

error can some one suggest me what needs to be done to successfully install virtualenv.

Comment: can you connect to  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py in web browser ? Then download it manually and run `sudo python downloaded_script.py`.

Comment: I am able to see the comments in my browser but the complete code is not available  as it is in binary, i tried using wget in terminal to download the resource from web but I am getting an error

Comment: you shouldn't see any comments in web browser. It should download python's script, not binary code.

Comment: I see the introduction within the comments and initial code followed by the random characters

Comment: all these comments and random characters (encoded in base64) is python's code which you should save in file `get-pip.py` and run it. Normally browser should save it in file. You can right click on link https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and use `"save as .."` (or similar) to save it.