# pip install fail: Terminal lists most recent attempts of package installation, won't install packages

Tags: python, matlab, api, terminal

In an attempt to access and run Matlab code via Jupyter notebook and Python, I tried installing 'matlab_kernal' (w/ typo) and 'matlab_kernel' as suggested by a blog, I didn't realize I needed MatLab, not MatLab Compiler Runtime.

I received the error:
"Collecting matlab_kernal
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matlab_kernal (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matlab_kernal"

As a work around, I found python code on GitHub that calculated the metric I wanted, but the author said I'd need to install 'MPI' from 'mpi4py'.

However, it seems my Terminal is now stuck on my previous installation attempts of 'matlab_kernal'. It lists my previous attempts to install these packages (see all white text above red error message in the attached screen capture).

I'm running: pip 18.1 from /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

I've tried:

- pip uninstall 'package'
- Terminal restart
- laptop restart

[Screenshot of Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oybdz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
pip install matlab-kernel
```

Try with `conda` as well:

```
 conda install -c pchrapka matlab_kernel
```

I think you're making a typo with `kernal`.

I am on `py3.7` with `pip v19.3`.

**Output**:

```
$ pip install matlab-kernel
Collecting matlab-kernel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/64/ad/5f471160ec33e2f0f3586d285cd5e3b6dff51027849f28369d43d1d57fd1/matlab_kernel-0.16.7-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=4.4.0 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matlab-kernel) (5.3.4)
Collecting metakernel>=0.23.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/a9/0cd74cfbc9c4aeb117bdb7fd9ff12c3890be34ef5c77932e00ef4afaca98/metakernel-0.24.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (208kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 246kB/s
Collecting wurlitzer>=1.0.2; platform_system != "Windows"
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/5e/f3bd8443bfdf96d2f5d10097d301076a9eb55637b7864e52d2d1a4d8c72a/wurlitzer-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matlab-kernel) (7.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.4.0->matlab-kernel) (18.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.1 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.4.0->matlab-kernel) (6.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.4.0->matlab-kernel) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.4.0->matlab-kernel) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.6.0 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.4.0->matlab-kernel) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>=4.2 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from metakernel>=0.23.0->matlab-kernel) (4.7.0)
Collecting portalocker
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/db/7bc703c0760df726839e0699b7f78a4d8217fdc9c7fcb1b51b39c5a22a4e/portalocker-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from metakernel>=0.23.0->matlab-kernel) (5.1.2)
Collecting ipyparallel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/82/aaa7a357845a98d4028f27c799f0d3bb2fe55fc1247c73dc712b4ae2344c/ipyparallel-6.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (198kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 204kB 698kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->matlab-kernel) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->matlab-kernel) (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->matlab-kernel) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->matlab-kernel) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->matlab-kernel) (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->matlab-kernel) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: appnope; sys_platform == "darwin" in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->matlab-kernel) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->matlab-kernel) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from traitlets->jupyter-client>=4.4.0->matlab-kernel) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from traitlets->jupyter-client>=4.4.0->matlab-kernel) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pexpect>=4.2->metakernel>=0.23.0->matlab-kernel) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=4.0.0->matlab-kernel) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.5.0 in /Users/siddheshpisal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/envs/ori_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython>=4.0.0->matlab-kernel) (0.5.1)
Installing collected packages: portalocker, ipyparallel, metakernel, wurlitzer, matlab-kernel
Successfully installed ipyparallel-6.2.4 matlab-kernel-0.16.7 metakernel-0.24.3 portalocker-1.5.2 wurlitzer-2.0.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3; however, version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch, but even when I try to install the package with the correct spelling or totally different packages, I still get an error for 'matlab_kernal'. Check out the image I provided, it lists all the previous installation attempts.

Comment: @GeoStephanieRae some package with a dependency on matlab-kernel might have spelled it wrong

Comment: Yup, I’ve tried installation with the correct spelling of kernel, I’ve also tried installing other packages, but any installation attempt errors out. 
Regardless of what package I try to install, the result is the same; terminal lists previous instal attempts (with various packages) and errors out with: "Collecting matlab_kernal Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matlab_kernal (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for matlab_kernal"

Answer (score 0):

It's a version issue for pip and MacOS

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745105/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-in-python)

terminal error in MacOS from command 'pip install 'package-name': 
"Collecting 'package-name' 
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 'package-name' (from versions: ) 
No matching distribution found for 'package-name'"

Uninstall pip and reinstall pip in terminal